# Is there a quick way to view the wp-cron schedule

Tags: wp-cron

I'm trying to work which plugin is triggering wp-cron. I know about the code: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_schedules , but I'd prefer to do something in the sql backend rather than write a plugin.

Comment: For future readers, there are convenient plugins to view cron schedules like [Cron Tasks Viewer](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/cron-task-viewer-redux/).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Why don't you just create a cron job, make a database dump and look where the info about the cron job is kept? That's what I did. As suspected, WordPress 3.5.1 keeps its cron jobs in the `{wp}_options` table under the name `'cron'`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_options`
WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%cron%'
```

Or through functions.php:

```
$cron_jobs = get_option( 'cron' );
var_dump($cron_jobs);
```

Comment: _"Why don't you just create a cron job, make a database dump and look where the info about the cron job is kept? "_ - Because OP didn't know how?

Answer (score 24):

You can use the WP-CLI.

From the command line, you can run the following command from the directory of your WordPress installation:

```
wp cron event list
```

It will display a table of the scheduled events, when it's set to run, and how often it's rescheduled.
Here is what was returned to me when I ran the command:
[image]

https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-cron-job/

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, if someone wish to check list of wordpress cron on server then use this `wp cron event list`

Comment: @HemantKumar That's exactly what Shreyl's answer said...

Comment: If anyone wants to get the cron list for a multisite then you've to define a site URL like this: `wp cron event list --url=http://domain.com/site_slug`

Answer (score 22):

WordPress has an undocumented function, `_get_cron_array()`, that returns an array of all currently scheduled tasks. We are going to use a crude but effective method to dump out all the tasks using `var_dump()`. For ease of use place the following code in the plugin:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( _get_cron_array() );
echo '</pre>';
```

For more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/simple-testing/

Comment: It seems that `_get_cron_array()` basically just calls `get_option('cron')`. Probably better to do that (as mentioned in the answer marked as correct) than use a function marked private (in its docblock).